# change direction of animation canvas element when it reaches the width of the canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am animating a rectangle across a canvas element using js. I want to change the direction of the the animation when the rectangle reaches the width of the canvas but cannot work out the logic as it turns once, but then goes to the right again, essentially sticking it to the width of the canvas.

Please see the code below to get a clearer understanding:

```
function startGame() {
   game.start();
   game.createSquare('red', 100, 10, 10, 10);
}

function updateGame() {
    game.clear();
    //lines below are causing issues
    if(game.x < game.canvas.width){
        game.x++;
    } else {
        game.x--; 
    }
    game.update();
}

var game = {
   //create the canvas element
   canvas: document.createElement('canvas'),

   //set up the canvas
   start: function () {
       this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
       this.canvas.height = 400;
       this.canvas.width = 400;
       document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas ,document.body.childNodes[0]);
    },

    //clear the canvas
    clear: function() {
       this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    },
    //create Square
    createSquare: function(color, height, width, x, y) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.color = color;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        this.update = function(){
            this.context.fillStyle = this.color;
            this.context.fillRect(this.x , this.y , this.width, this.height);
        }
       }
     }
    startGame();
    setInterval(updateGame,50);
```

Comment: You should have a **velocity** property for your rectangle. When your condition `game.x < game.canvas.width` is *false*, you invert the velocity. And you always do `game.x += velocity`.

Comment: @PierreC. I believe it's a bit more complicated than adding velocity. The speed depends on the elapsed time between two frames. Even if the elapsedTime set is "50" ms in setInterval... it's not "100%" certain to trigger the method every 50ms. So you should always base your velocity on time difference to get accurate movement.

Comment: @Loïc Faure-Lacroix To make a really good animation (smooth 60FPS) you should use requestAnimationFrame with performance.now() to get accurate time delta between frames (like in this example http://jsbin.com/jitiquzive/edit?html,output), but for this simple problem let's start form basics.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix I don't see where the OP talked about problems regarding frames or lag. From what I see if he sets a `velocity` to `-1` or `1` his problem would be fixed. Your point is totally right, but I just tried to answer the question asked. The accepted answer follows what I said :)

Comment: @PierreC. calm down guys! everyone is happy! question is answered and knowledge has been gained.

Comment: @PierreC. Yes, I see your point. it's easier that way to control. Technically the velocity can be computed later to something else than -1, 1.

Comment: arguing doesn't mean we are angry ^^
@LoïcFaure-Lacroix Of course. It is, IMO, better to focus on the question asked. OP may (will) face these problems sooner or later and comeback for help eventually! Anyway, bonne journée :)

Comment: @PierreC. bonne journée, and you will be the first person I will contact when i run into issues with smooth animations going forward! bisous! x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a small change is needed to make it work. Explanation in code below.
Working example https://jsbin.com/gafetoxapu/edit?js,output

```
function startGame() {
   game.start();
   game.createSquare('red', 100, 10, 10, 10);
}

function updateGame() {
    game.clear();
    //lines below are causing issues
    game.x += game.delta; // set new position

    // if rectangle touches right side (remember about the width of rectangle),
    // or touches left side of canvas, revert direction
    if(game.x > game.canvas.width - game.width || game.x <= 0){
       game.delta *= -1;
    }

    game.update();
    }

var game = {
   //create the canvas element
   canvas: document.createElement('canvas'),

   //set up the canvas
   start: function () {
       this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
       this.canvas.height = 400;
       this.canvas.width = 400;
       document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas ,document.body.childNodes[0]);
    },

    //clear the canvas
    clear: function() {
       this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    },
    //create Square
    createSquare: function(color, height, width, x, y) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.color = color;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.delta = 1; // this is speed and direction of movement 

        this.update = function(){
            this.context.fillStyle = this.color;
            this.context.fillRect(this.x , this.y , this.width, this.height);
        }
       }
     }
    startGame();
    setInterval(updateGame,50);
```

Comment: I like using the `*` to invert the number! thanks for your help!